# Service worker registration unresponsive

Tags: electron, service-worker

Electron 1.7.6 does not respond to a service worker registration, while this works on Firefox and Chrome. The promise is neither resolved or rejected, and the console.log calls in the service worker code are not called. Under the Dev Tools, Service Worker section shows it as "installing".

Interestingly clicking on "unregister", would unstuck the registration and it would register fine, but I can't reproduce that anymore.

This happens with any service worker code I've tried, even when all code is commented. Also, the code works fine on Chrome and Firefox. Therefore, I'm not posting code.